# Why does my iterm window say -bash: alias: -G”: not found

Tags: macos, terminal

I type in ls -la and it shows nothing. It should say myname at Mac in ~ i think.

This all happened after I made a .bash_profile file to get my terminal to show multi colors. I can't find the .bash_profile file since it's hidden, so I can't delete it.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please post the content of your `.bash_profile` file (see my answer). But **not** as a screenshot, please copy the text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my iterm window say -bash: alias: -G”: not found](http://superuser.com/questions/515208/why-does-my-iterm-window-say-bash-alias-g-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one or more errors in your `.bash_profile`

- `alias ls='"command'` does not provoke any error but does not make any sense: you substitute `ls` with `"command` which is the beginning of a string
- you have somewhere another alias declaration with an error (you should post the content of your `.bash_profile`) but look for a `-G` in an alias declaration

The file is hidden in the finder but you can:

- delete it with `rm .bash_profile`
- edit it with `emacs`: `emacs .bash_profile`
- rename it `mv .bash_profile newname`
- ...

To see the content try

- `cat .bash_profile` or `less .bash_profile`